# How to Play Facebook Video from HTML?

Tags: css, html, facebook, video

I have read many posts, forums, blog Posts on how to add video in HTML document, but i am  still unable to find out how to add Facebook Video in HTML document.

If replace Facebook URL with Youtube Video URL, it works fine, but i want to add Facebook Videos in my HTML document.

I have written the following code, Kindly check it and guide me how to play facebook videos.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    VIDEO

   <iframe width="420" height="345"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=600199933404165">
    </iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a interesting article about Facebook embed videos. it working Good.

```
<object width="400" height="224" > 
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /> 
 <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" /> 
 <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/xxx" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  
   allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="400" height="224"> 
 </embed> 
</object>
```

link Value:- 
Example: http://www.facebook.com/v/600199933404165

Answer (score 0):

Well , your html code will show the whole page not the video only . 
to get the video right click at the top of the video then press inspect element and then look for something like this

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v1/y3/r/QOs3-Yl0Nl1.swf" width="720" height="405" style="display: block;" id="swf_id_53a9595077b449a57484665" name="swf_id_53a9595077b449a57484665" bgcolor="#000000" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" salign="tl" scale="noscale" wmode="opaque" flashvars="params=%7B%22autoplay%22%3Afalse%2C%22autoplay_reason%22%3A%22unknown%22%2C%22autoplay_setting%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22autorewind%22%3Atrue%2C%22default_hd%22%3Atrue%2C%22dtsg%22%3A%22AQEdKr9u4iLr%22%2C%22inline_player%22%3Afalse%2C%22lsd%22%3Anull%2C%22min_progress_update%22%3A300%2C%22pixel_ratio%22%3A1%2C%22player_origin%22%3A%22photos%22%2C%22preload%22%3Afalse%2C%22source%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22start_index%22%3A0%2C%22start_muted%22%3Afalse%2C%22use_spotlight%22%3Afalse%2C%22video_data%22%3A%5B%7B%22hd_src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvideo-ak-xpa1%5C%2Fv%5C%2Ft43.1792-2%5C%2F1910863_600357540055071_202972839_n.mp4%3Foh%3Dfd5af14569a239d747883823e8797cae%26oe%3D53A9728C%26__gda__%3D1403614518_4f21777535dfcf20c41f43b5004c4af5%22%2C%22is_hds%22%3Afalse%2C%22index%22%3A0%2C%22rotation%22%3A0%2C%22sd_src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvideo-ak-xap1%5C%2Fv%5C%2Ft42.1790-2%5C%2F10008102_600357536721738_1444190974_n.mp4%3Foh%3Da3aed71685504c4cae1ccfbdc8ae840e%26oe%3D53A97633%26__gda__%3D1403614888_e138a4b8bc770d678391d1af0ba31da4%22%2C%22thumbnail_src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvthumb-ak-xap1%5C%2Ft15.0-10%5C%2F1940447_600357590055066_600199933404165_56479_2145_b.jpg%22%2C%22thumbnail_height%22%3A720%2C%22thumbnail_width%22%3A1280%2C%22video_duration%22%3A182%2C%22video_id%22%3A%22600199933404165%22%2C%22subtitles_src%22%3Anull%7D%5D%2C%22show_captions%22%3Afalse%7D&amp;width=720&amp;height=405&amp;user=100002092438880&amp;log=no&amp;div_id=id_53a9595077b449a57484665&amp;swf_id=swf_id_53a9595077b449a57484665&amp;browser=Chrome+35.0.1916.153&amp;tracking_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fpixel.facebook.com&amp;post_form_id=&amp;string_table=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fflash_strings.php%2Ft97472%2Fen_US">
```

then add it on your page .

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

    VIDEO



    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v1/y3/r/QOs3-Yl0Nl1.swf" width="720" height="405" style="display: block;" id="swf_id_53a9595077b449a57484665" name="swf_id_53a9595077b449a57484665" bgcolor="#000000" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" salign="tl" scale="noscale" wmode="opaque" flashvars="params=%7B%22autoplay%22%3Afalse%2C%22autoplay_reason%22%3A%22unknown%22%2C%22autoplay_setting%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22autorewind%22%3Atrue%2C%22default_hd%22%3Atrue%2C%22dtsg%22%3A%22AQEdKr9u4iLr%22%2C%22inline_player%22%3Afalse%2C%22lsd%22%3Anull%2C%22min_progress_update%22%3A300%2C%22pixel_ratio%22%3A1%2C%22player_origin%22%3A%22photos%22%2C%22preload%22%3Afalse%2C%22source%22%3A%22permalink%22%2C%22start_index%22%3A0%2C%22start_muted%22%3Afalse%2C%22use_spotlight%22%3Afalse%2C%22video_data%22%3A%5B%7B%22hd_src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvideo-ak-xpa1%5C%2Fv%5C%2Ft43.1792-2%5C%2F1910863_600357540055071_202972839_n.mp4%3Foh%3Dfd5af14569a239d747883823e8797cae%26oe%3D53A9728C%26__gda__%3D1403614518_4f21777535dfcf20c41f43b5004c4af5%22%2C%22is_hds%22%3Afalse%2C%22index%22%3A0%2C%22rotation%22%3A0%2C%22sd_src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-video-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvideo-ak-xap1%5C%2Fv%5C%2Ft42.1790-2%5C%2F10008102_600357536721738_1444190974_n.mp4%3Foh%3Da3aed71685504c4cae1ccfbdc8ae840e%26oe%3D53A97633%26__gda__%3D1403614888_e138a4b8bc770d678391d1af0ba31da4%22%2C%22thumbnail_src%22%3A%22https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Ffbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net%5C%2Fhvthumb-ak-xap1%5C%2Ft15.0-10%5C%2F1940447_600357590055066_600199933404165_56479_2145_b.jpg%22%2C%22thumbnail_height%22%3A720%2C%22thumbnail_width%22%3A1280%2C%22video_duration%22%3A182%2C%22video_id%22%3A%22600199933404165%22%2C%22subtitles_src%22%3Anull%7D%5D%2C%22show_captions%22%3Afalse%7D&amp;width=720&amp;height=405&amp;user=100002092438880&amp;log=no&amp;div_id=id_53a9595077b449a57484665&amp;swf_id=swf_id_53a9595077b449a57484665&amp;browser=Chrome+35.0.1916.153&amp;tracking_domain=https%3A%2F%2Fpixel.facebook.com&amp;post_form_id=&amp;string_table=https%3A%2F%2Fs-static.ak.facebook.com%2Fflash_strings.php%2Ft97472%2Fen_US">

</body>

</html>
```

Copy and paste it . this will show the facebook video .

PS : the code above displays the video you are looking for .

Answer (score 0):

Make the get request to `<videoid>`-

```
\GET /{video-id}
```

In response you will get the actual video source in `source`. Just use this with your `iframe` as-

```
<iframe src="{source}"></iframe>
```